# Move package to a different location, but keep exporting it from old

Tags: go

I have a package `x/y` that was moved to `x/abc/y`. Is there a way to keep exporting it also as `x/y`. So that projects that use it as a dependency can still use old import path?

Comment: Create a new package at x/y that aliases all exported identifiers to the new package. See the ioutil package in the standard library, for instance; most of it has been moved to the io and os packages.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths the part with the meta-tag (or google for vanity import).